# Resumable upload from Java client to Grails web application?

Tags: java, grails, upload, inputstream, resume-upload

After almost 2 workdays of Googling and trying several different possibilities I found throughout the web, I'm asking this question here, hoping that I might finally get an answer.

### First of all, here's **what I want to do**:

I'm developing a client and a server application with the purpose of exchanging a lot of *large* files between multiple clients on a single server. The client is developed in pure **Java** (JDK 1.6), while the web application is done in **Grails** (2.0.0).

As the purpose of the client is to allow users to exchange a lot of large files (usually about 2GB each), I have to implement it in a way, so that the uploads are **resumable**, i.e. the users are able to stop and resume uploads at any time.

#### Here's **what I did** so far:

I actually managed to do what I wanted to do and stream large files to the server while still being able to pause and resume uploads using raw sockets. I would send a regular request to the server (using Apache's HttpClient library) to get the server to send me a port that was free for me to use, then open a ServerSocket on the server and connect to that particular socket from the client.

#### Here's **the problem with that**:

Actually, there are at least two problems with that:

1. I open those ports myself, so I have to manage open and used ports myself. This is quite error-prone.
2. I actually circumvent Grails' ability to manage a huge amount of (concurrent) connections.

### Finally, here's **what I'm supposed to do now and the problem**:

As the problems I mentioned above are unacceptable, I am now supposed to use Java's URLConnection/HttpURLConnection classes, while still sticking to Grails.

Connecting to the server and sending simple requests is no problem at all, everything worked fine. The problems started when I tried to use the streams (the connection's OutputStream in the client and the request's InputStream in the server). Opening the client's OutputStream and writing data to it is as easy as it gets. But reading from the request's InputStream seems impossible to me, as that stream is **always empty**, as it seems.

### Example Code

Here's an example of the **server side** (Groovy controller):

```
def test() {
    InputStream inStream = request.inputStream
    
    if(inStream != null) {
        int read = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        long total = 0;
        
        println "Start reading"
        
        while((read = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            println "Read " + read + " bytes from input stream buffer"      //<-- this is NEVER called
        }       
        
        println "Reading finished"
        println "Read a total of " + total + " bytes"   // <-- 'total' will always be 0 (zero)
    } else {
        println "Input Stream is null"      // <-- This is NEVER called
    }
}
```

This is what I did on the **client side** (Java class):

```
public void connect() {
    final URL url = new URL("myserveraddress");
    final byte[] message = "someMessage".getBytes();        // Any byte[] - will be a file one day
    HttpURLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");                     // other methods - same result
    
    // Write message 
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    out.writeBytes(message);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    
    // Actually connect
    connection.connect();                                   // is this placed correctly?
    
    // Get response
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    
    String line = null;
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);                   // Prints the whole server response as expected
    }
    
    in.close();
}
```

As I mentioned, the problem is that `request.inputStream` always yields an empty InputStream, so I am never able to read anything from it (of course). But as that is exactly what I'm trying to do (so I can stream the file to be uploaded to the server, read from the InputStream and save it to a file), this is rather disappointing.

I tried **different HTTP methods**, **different data payloads**, and also rearranged the code over and over again, but did not seem to be able to solve the problem.

### What I hope to find

I hope to find a solution to my problem, of course. Anything is highly appreciated: hints, code snippets, library suggestions and so on. Maybe I'm even having it all wrong and need to go in a totally different direction.

So, how can I implement resumable file uploads for rather large (binary) files from a Java client to a Grails web application without manually opening ports on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP GET method have special headers for range retrieval: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35 It's used by most downloaders to do resumable download from server.

As I understand, there are no standard practice for using this headers for POST/PUT request, but it's up to you, right? You can make pretty standard Grails controller, that will accept standard http upload, with header like `Range: bytes=500-999`. And controller should put this 500 uploaded bytes from client into file, starting at position 500

At this case you don't need to open any socket, and make own protocols, etc.

P.S. 500 bytes is just a example, probably you're using much bigger parts.

Answer (score 0):

**Client Side Java Programming:**

```
    public class NonFormFileUploader {
    static final String UPLOAD_URL= "http://localhost:8080/v2/mobileApp/fileUploadForEOL";


    static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // takes file path from first program's argument
        String filePath = "G:/study/GettingStartedwithGrailsFinalInfoQ.pdf";
        File uploadFile = new File(filePath);

        System.out.println("File to upload: " + filePath);

        // creates a HTTP connection
        URL url = new URL(UPLOAD_URL);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        // sets file name as a HTTP header
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("fileName", uploadFile.getName());

        // opens output stream of the HTTP connection for writing data
        OutputStream outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();

        // Opens input stream of the file for reading data
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead = -1;

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            System.out.println("bytesRead:"+bytesRead);
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            outputStream.flush();
        }

        System.out.println("Data was written.");
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // reads server's response
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String response = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Server's response: " + response);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Server returned non-OK code: " + responseCode);
        }
    }
 }
```

**Server Side Grails Programme:**

*Inside the controller:*

```
def fileUploadForEOL(){
    def result
    try{
        result = mobileAppService.fileUploadForEOL(request);
    }catch(Exception e){
        log.error "Exception in fileUploadForEOL service",e
    }
    render result as JSON
}
```

*Inside the Service Class:*

```
    def fileUploadForEOL(request){
    def status = false;
    int code = 500
    def map = [:]
    try{
    String fileName = request.getHeader("fileName");
    File saveFile = new File(SAVE_DIR + fileName);

    System.out.println("===== Begin headers =====");
    Enumeration<String> names = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = names.nextElement();
        System.out.println(headerName + " = " + request.getHeader(headerName));        
    }
    System.out.println("===== End headers =====\n");

    // opens input stream of the request for reading data
    InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();

    // opens an output stream for writing file
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer);

    long count =  bytesRead

    while(bytesRead != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
      bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer);
      count += bytesRead
    }
     println "count:"+count
    System.out.println("Data received.");
    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();

    System.out.println("File written to: " + saveFile.getAbsolutePath());

    code = 200

    }catch(Exception e){
        mLogger.log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE,"Exception in fileUploadForEOL",e);
    }finally{
        map <<["code":code]
    }
    return map
}
```

I have tried with above code it is worked for me(only for file size 3 to 4MB, but for small size files some bytes of code missing or not even coming but in request header content-length is coming, not sure why it is happening.)